# How can I convert all input to uppercase in angular material?

Tags: angular

[I want to convert all input to uppercase. But I am using a material tag which does not allow me to to do using normal uppercasepipe. Is there any way to do it in material tag?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOZh.jpg)

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="globals.isAdding"> 
   <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="FirstName"
    [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value=$event.toUpperCase()"> 
</mat-form-field>
```

I have tried using other way too

**HTML code**

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="globals.isAdding"> 
   <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="FirstName" 
    [ngModel]="dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal | myPipe"
    (ngModelChange)="dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal=$event" 
   type="text"> 
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS code**

```
import { UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common'; 

@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'}) 
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform{ 

   transform(val){ 
     return val.toUpperCase() 
   } 
} 

@Component(...) 
export class TestCode implements OnInit {...}
```

Comment: Put the code you have done

Comment: <mat-form-field *ngIf="globals.isAdding">
     <input matInput placeholder="Name" 
     formControlName="FirstName" 
     [ngModel]="value" 
     (ngModelChange)="value=$event.toUpperCase()">
</mat-form-field>

Comment: I have tried using other way too

Comment: HTML code

<mat-form-field *ngIf="globals.isAdding">
<input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="FirstName" 
 [ngModel]="dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal | myPipe" 
        (ngModelChange)="dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal=$event" type="text">
</mat-form-field>

Comment: TS code
import { UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(val){
    return val.toUpperCase()
  }
}
@Component(...)
export class TestCode implements OnInit {...}

Answer (score 5):

With a reactive forms you can subscribe on valueCahnges event and patch the value in it

```
this.myForm.get('state').valueChanges
        .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged() //it is needed because patchValue emits execution again
        )
        .subscribe((value: string) => {
            this.myForm.get('state').patchValue(value.toUpperCase());
        })
```

Comment: this works. However it move the cursor to the end of the text. When you are typing something in the middle the effect is not so pleasant

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML put the below:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="FirstName" type="text"
    [ngModel]="dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal"
    (ngModelChange)="changeUpperCase(dailyScheduleForm.lineupOriginTerminal)">
```

And in your TS file put below:

```
changeUpperCase(textToUpper: string){
        console.log("textToUpper: "+ textToUpper); 
        var newWord = textToUpper.toUpperCase();
        console.log("The word in upper case: "+ newWord);    

  }
```

[image]

### For input value always in  uppercase

```
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Name" #input [value]="input.value.toUpperCase()" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

Comment: I tried. It is still not working. Neither giving an error nor giving an expected output.

Comment: Check what is being saved in variable textToUpper. Try to debug or put console.log. Because this is the basic function to convert to upperCase. Attached the screenshot.

Comment: I am getting the output in console but not in the input field. How can I get the uppercase in input field?

Comment: okay I did that way and it works. But at first it gives the error saying "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" and when I type it gives the correct output. Any solution for this error?

Comment: May be in your code the value is undefined initially , so this error. Put the final html code.  Either  you can initialize to solve this. Anyway, I dont think that it will impact the functionality.

Comment: My final html code is like this.
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!globals.isAdding">
<input matInput placeholder="Terminal" formControlName="Terminal" #Terminal maxlength="5"
          value="{{dailyScheduleHeaderInfo.Terminal}}" disabled [ngModel]="dailyScheduleHeaderInfo.Terminal" (ngModelChange)="dailyScheduleHeaderInfo.Terminal=$event.toUpperCase()">
</mat-form-field>

Comment: I have tried to initialize the values with null. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the javascript version of the input event

Add this into your input's HTML

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Comment: Elegant, I added `.replace()` to format for my accepted character list, and this is perfect without adding more dependancies.

Comment: I should note, the one downside to this approach is that it causes the cursor to jump to the end of the input on each character entered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the directive api. Here is an example of a directive to uppercase a name and only accept letters :

```
export function formatName(val: string): string {
    return val.toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-zA-ZÀ-ú\'\s\-]/, "")
}


@Directive({
    selector: '[sanitizeName]',
})
export class SanitizeNameDirective {
    constructor(private control: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    public onInput(): void {
            this.control.control.setValue(formatName(this.control.value));
    }
}
```

Then when you want to uppercase the name field of a given form :

```
<input type="text" matInput sanitizeName [formControl]="name" placeholder="Ex. DUPONT">
```

Don't forget to declare your directive in your app module.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this problem and the CSS approach worked for me. Just add `style="text-transform: uppercase"`.

```
<input
  #input
  maxlength="128"
  [(ngModel)]="task.taskId"
  matInput
  placeholder="Task Id"
  required
  style="text-transform: uppercase"
/>
```